# Is a Pantheon of Abstract Gods a Bad Idea?

Tags: religion, gods

I am currently working on a Homebrew setting for Dungeons and Dragons, and I wanted some feedback on how I was thinking about handling the pantheon in this setting.

There are only six deities within this setting, all with their own domains of things that they are in charge of. However, the main difference that will be present is that despite the fact that their actions and whims are present in the world through clerics, temples, and other assorted followers, none of them have a set name.

An example of this would be the God of Trickery, Seas, and Darkness. Though he is tied to all these sub-domains, the only name he would ever have is one his followers gave him or his titles.

What I want to know is, is this an inherently bad way of going about this, or would it be able to work? On one hand, I can see how not giving these gods names can make them feel less like characters in their own mythology, but on the other hands, I'd also like to explore how that lack of a name would influence the followers of a given god. i.e. Two factions arguing over what to call their deity, and how far they would take that conflict over something so minor.

Comment: I'd imagine that the humans who are worshipping the gods will name them. Even if the name ultimately doesn't matter, we humans love naming things. We personify anything we can - death is a human skeleton, winter is an old and wizened guy (or lady), companies adopt a company mascot to represent them. Fun fact, the [Michelin Man](https://costumespecialists.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michelin-Man-Bibendum-Corporate-Mascot.jpg) has a name and it's Bidendum. I don't see why each group of human worshippers of the same deity won't just give their god a name.

Comment: Hmm. Let's see. What are [*Victoria*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_(mythology)), [*Justitia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Justice), [*Nike*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike_(mythology)), [*Dike*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dike_(mythology)), if not purely abstract deities? The Romans had a veritable host of them; check to see if your Latin is good enough to understand the following names: Jugatinus, Cinxia, Fluonia, Alemona, Sentia, Postverta, Lucina, Vagitanus, Levana, Rumina, Nundina, Agenoria, Domiduca, Fabulinus, Locutius, Tutelina, and, of course, Anna Perenna.

Comment: You may find this page interesting reading. It is a bunch of examples from both literature and real life where entities accumulate so many names that none of them is exactly definitive: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/IHaveManyNames/RealLife

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile, in the real world:

- For almost two thousand years, Christians and Hebrews have called their God, *God*, or *Lord*, many, maybe even most of them never bothering to learn that He actually has a Name. In recent times, much to my astonishment, I have even encountered (in American English) the fantastic misspelling *G-d*, as if *God* was the Name of our God and the writer was afraid of spelling it out. (No, the God of Abraham is not named *God*...)

  The Name of God never appears in the specifically Christian part of the Bible, and for some nineteen hundred years the Hebrews have refrained from uttering the Name of God; to the point that eventually there even was a minor dispute among learned men on what that most powerful and holy Name actually is.

  (When  Joseph Franklin Rutherford founded his novel religion in the second half of the 19th century, based on a re-interpretation the Hebrew and Christian holy Scriptures, he called it Jehovah's Witnesses, because he believed that the God of the Hebrews and Christians was named Jehovah, or *Yehowah* in the original Hebrew. To this level had sunk the ignorance of men about the name of their God.)
- The God of Islam is always called *God*, or *Allah* in Arabic, never by His Name. To the best of my knowledge, the Holy Quran never mentions the Name of God.

---

Addendum prompted by @G0BLiN:

1. Names are usually *meaningful*, that is, they actually *mean* something in the language of the linguistic community which is using the names. In the modern western world we are so used to using (badly mangled) foreign names, mostly Hebrew names and Greek names, which are of course meaningless to us, that most people do not realize that most of those many names in the Greek history and mythology they learned at school are actually Greek words or phrases. I blame it on the abandonment of a good solid classical education. (And most of the names in the Bible are meaningful in Hebrew, but I don't know Hebrew.) Examples:

   - Gods: Ares = Bane / Ruin, Deimos = Dread, Dike = Justice / Retribution, Gaia = Land / Earth, Hermes = Boundary Marker, Nike = Victory, Pandora = All Gifted, Phobos = Fear, Prometheus = Forethought, Themis = Justice / Equity, Thetis = Placer / Setter.

     I also mention the primordial deities whose names are simply everyday words: Aether, Ananke = Necessity, Chaos, Eros, Hemera = Day, Nyx = Night.

     In fact, when the name of a Greek god is meaningless in Greek and does not have a credible Indo-European etymology this is taken as definitive proof that the deity in question has been adopted from a non-Greek religion. So for example Zeus (who has a perfectly good Indo-European etymology, meaning Luminous, and a perfect parallel in the Latin word *dies* = day and the name Ju-piter = Luminous Father) is an ancestral Greek deity, but Aphrodite (whose name is meaningless in Greek and has no reasonable Indo-European etymology) must have been adopted from the pre-existing population the Greeks found in Greece.
   - Mortals: Andromache = Fighter of Men, Andromeda = Ruler of Men, Archimedes = Paramount Ruler, Aristotle = Noble Goal, Berenice = Bringer of Victory, Cassiopeia = Bright Face, Cleopatra = Glory of Her Father, Electra = Amber, Heracles = Glory of Hera, Herodotus = Granted by Hera, Plato = Broad-Shouldered, Sophocles = Glory of Wisdom, Themistocles = Glory of Justice.

   Now the point is that if the Greeks saw no problem in naming their war god "Bane", why wouldn't a mere game call the god of trickery Trickster?
2. The Romans had a veritable host of purely abstract deities, whose names are usually transparent derivaties from the words describing what they do; the following is a very small sample:

   - Victoria, Justitia, Jugatinus = Binder (as in matrimony), Cinxia = Belter (of the bride as part of the marriage ceremony), Fluonia = Flower (of the blood in the womb), Alemona = Nourisher (of the young children), Sentia = Senser (gives sentience to children), Postverta = Turner (of the baby in the womb, for birth), Lucina = Lighter, Vagitanus = Opener (of the baby's mouth after birth), Levana = Lifter (of the child), Rumina = Suckler, Nundina = Niner (on the ninth day the child was named), Agenoria = Activator, Domiduca = Bringer Home, Fabulinus = Maker of Speech, Locutius = Speechifier, Tutelina = Guardian, and, of course, [Anna Perenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Perenna) = Yearly Year-Round.

   One of the most important Roman goddesses was called [*Bona Dea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bona_Dea) "Good Goddess"; she may or may not have had a proper name, but in any case we don't know it, as she was always called Bona Dea (or variations, *Feminea Dea* "Goddess of Women", *Sancta* "Holy").

   Entire classes of Roman deities have no personal names; suffice to mention the [Lares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lares), guardian deities of the home, and the [Penates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di_Penates), the guardians of the store-room.

Comment: Your comment above about Roman abstract deities will supplement this answer nicely - especially as it presents a pantheon incorporating abstract gods, while this answer focuses on monotheistic religions.

Comment: @G0BLiN: OK, done.

Comment: “Aphrodite (whose name is meaningless in Greek and has no reasonable Indo-European etymology) must have been adopted from the pre-existing population the Greeks found in Greece.” My understanding is that the scholarly consensus is that she’s the Hellenised version of Ishtar, whose cult got imported into Greece during the Bronze Age Collapse.

Comment: monotheism makes for a bad comparison, calling several different beings just God will get confusing very quickly.

Comment: In all Native American tribal stories I’ve heard, from multiple tribes, Coyote never has a name other than Coyote unless it is as a nickname, Trickster (in English). “Coyote” is actually the name in a lot of the native languages since it is sourced in the Aztec.

Comment: @AlexP - nicely done, pity I don't have another +1 ;-)

Comment: @nick012000: There is no sane way to get from Astarte / Ishtar to Aphrodite; there is no sound correspondence. As far as I know the most common view is that her name is of pre-Hellenic (possibly, just possibly Semitic), but the exact derivation is not yet known.

Comment: @AlexP The myth of her arrival involves her landing on a particular island that had a colony from the same culture as Ishtar, early depictions of her involve a warlike element that shared with Ishtar, and there aren't any records of her in Greece before the Bronze Age Collapse. Here's a Youtube video discussing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIUq0pfAskU

Comment: @nick012000: Yes, her cult originated in Cyprus. Yes, her name has not been found in Linear B inscriptions. Yes, she is pre-Hellenic, or possibly non-Hellenic. But, I repeat, her name most definitely cannot be derived from Astarte / Innana / Ishtar in any reasonable way. So, unless you have a serious linguistic work showing a credible derivation, for the moment we cannot identify her pre-Hellenic or non-Hellenic source.

Comment: @AlexP You're asking for something that doesn't exist, because she was imported into Greece during the Dark Ages caused by the Bronze Ages Collapse. We don't have any written records from the time because the Greeks *forgot how to write*.

Comment: @nick012000: I am not asking for a written record. I am asking for a credible etymology for the name Aphrodite. Historical linguistics is a science for real.

Comment: @AlexP There's other forms of evidence, though, that you're completely ignoring. How did "Astarte" get turned into "Aphrodite"? We don't know as a result of a lack of written records from the time due to the apocalyptic collapse of civilization going on then, but based on the evidence we do have, we can say that it almost definitely did somehow.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather backwards to how things are normally done. If a deity is given or allocated a role in the pantheon, they are individualized by giving them names. In Indo European cultures, you can trace the deity from their original name in Proto Indo European mostly because they are carrying out the same role in the pantheon, regardless if it is the original P.I.E. Deity or the "modern" one.

http://www.piereligion.org/piemyth.html

> Creation Myths
>
> - Primal Cow Creation Myth (“World made from the Body of a Giant Bovine”, attested in 5 of the 11 language families.) For a full discussion of the forms of this myth, see Creation Myth of the Indo-Europeans and the Myth of Ymir.
>
>   - Birth of the Horse Twins from the grain/horse mother (Cox, p. 234; found in 7 of the 11 language groups.)
>   - Danu killed and cut open to produce a river (a Partition Creation myth; found in at least 3 of the 11 language families.)
>   - Time gives birth to the Sun and the Moon, see How Lleu Lhaw Gyffes Got his Name.
>
> Cyclic or Seasonal Myths
>
> - *Perkunos, a Storm God loses his “weapon of power” then uses it to kill winter (Cox, p. 559; found in 5 of the 11 language groups.)
>
>   - Cloud/cows stolen from the Sun God by the Wind God and then returned (Cox, p. 232; found in 4 of the 11 language groups.)
>   - Dying Corn God, dies and is reborn, causes seasons (Frazer, Vol. 8 and 9 of the Golden Bough, esp. Vol. 9, p. 412-423; found in 4 of the 11 language families.) The John Barleycorn song is widely recognized as a form of this myth.
>   - Uncle Water (Apam Napat or Neptune) melts the ice and releases the water causing flooding (Gamkrelidze and Ivanov, p. 582-3; found in 5 of the 11 language families.)
>
> Others
>
> - Quest of the golden apples of immortality, usually by a Wind God (Cox, p. 512; in 4 of the 11 language families.) #cultgod
>
> Culture Myths: Stories in which some godlike being teaches culture or the “arts of civilization” (actually technologies) to humans are found in all cultures. The culture myths of the Indo-Europeans tell how the Culture Gods taught humans how to make fire, the proper way to kill and butcher an animal (sacrifice), religious rituals and law codes, smithing, weaving, ploughing and healing. Culture Gods (e.g. Prometheus and Loki) sometimes have an intermediate position between Gods and humans. They are certainly supernatural, but they often die or are tortured by other Gods for their beneficence to humans; nevertheless they are often revived and worshiped like regular Gods. Mallory and Adams call them Craft Gods and argue that they are not linguistically reconstructible; however Cox compares Greek Prometheus with Hindu Pramanthu (p. 421, Cox). Smith Gods, a subset of the Culture Gods, are slightly reconstructible according to Mallory and Adams (p. 410, Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World).

So while there may be a great deal of similarities in terms of what role the gods play in a pantheon, they always are individually named. This provides connection between them and their worshippers, eliminates any ambiguities about who you are referring to and follows normal human conventions when speaking about others.

Comment: +1 for using Proto-Indo-European example.

Comment: Individually named, but maybe not uniquely named. “And he will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.” — Bible, Isaiah 9:6

Comment: A tricky answer. I would agree that a god would be given individualised name, however, that name *would* probably mean some aspect of that god's **role** as per AlexP's answer. From your example, Perkunas is a storm god, but the name (with slight modifications) also means "thunder" in the two remaining live Baltic languages.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing inherently wrong with this.  So long as you can piece together the reasons and consequences for why it is, you should be fine.

**Precidents of Nameless Deities**

As one fictional example In D&D's Eberron setting, the Dark Six are named by a title as opposed to by a given name.  Two of them are known as The Traveller and The Devourer and from what I recall off-hand, there is no indication that they have a proper name.  At least one used in common company.

For a modern real-world example, it has been brought up that the Abrahamic faiths do not name their god, only refering to him by the title of God.

**Following the Concept**

First of all, I think it might be valid to figure out why your six-strong pantheon of gods are unnamed to the mortals.  This is not something your players will ever have to know, but a reason might help you flesh out the rest of the things for your world.

That typed, your unnamed deities can follow a similar pattern as the two examples above.  Us mortals like to name things, so we will call them *something*, even if that is not their True Name.  Stories, myths, and legends will be passed down and they will adopt, inherit, or collect titles over the years.

**Following Logic**

If these deities are a world-wide religion, then they may only collect a very small number of titles.  If they present different aspects in different parts of your world, then I would expect them to have different titles in different regions.  Possibly even different levels of importance/power based on what deitiy holds the biggest sway over mortal lives there.

Different groups of people may have different names/titles for the same deity and that is perfectly fine.  It may also be that different aspects of their portfolios grant them a different name, and even a different cult.  This might also be a reflection of how each of the six deities of your world are viewed by the varous societies in the world.

Comment: you see this is several other works of fiction too, RWBY, brian sandersons works, and goblin slayer all come to mind, gods named with title or just their primary domain are common. A lot of real human gods "names" are just what they represent, Love, War, ect.

Answer (score 2):

**Neil Gaiman's Sandman series did it the way you propose.**

[image: the endless]

https://ungoliantschilde.tumblr.com/post/89382208444/quite-frankly-frank-quitely-is-an-incredible

> The Endless (Destiny, Death, Dream, Destruction, Desire, Despair, and
> Delirium) are a group of fictional beings appearing in American comic
> books published by DC Comics imprint Vertigo. The characters embody
> powerful forces or aspects of the universe in the comic book series
> The Sandman, by Neil Gaiman. They have existed since the dawn of time
> and are thought to be among the most powerful beings in the
> existence.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbtJg.jpg) They are distinct from and more powerful than most gods.
> Dream is the protagonist of The Sandman series, but all of the Endless
> play major roles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_(comics)

The Sandman series is truly excellent in as many ways as comic books can be excellent.  It does not suffer for having the abstract Endless "named" what they represent.  They have other names too, of course.  You can do it the same way.

Comment: Dream collects names the way a floor collects dust: incidentally, continuously, and only as long as it takes someone to get around to sweeping up the detritus. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Titles

Most likely they will have a "name" that is just what they personify. In terry pratchett's discworld you have anthropomorphic personifications, although Death says her prefers the term "avatar". Examples include Death, War, Truth, Fate. You have an odd one out, Luck, who is only ever referred to as "the Lady" becasue invoking her name is bad luck, like the building you are in catching fire the minute you say it bad luck. Many historical gods started this way and as languages changed titles became names.

The god of trickery may simply be called "Deception" or "the Trickster" Your only real decision is direct or indirect titles.

In Brian Sanderson's cosmere the major gods are all aspects of a single dead monogod. examples include Cultivation, Ruin, Preservation, Odium, Honor. As a twist they have no power outside their domain, ruin for instance has no power to create, preservation lack the ability to destroy.

More formal indirect titles instead of names will be likely if they have multiple domains. Even in "real" historic gods, Odin was called The Allfather, Thor The Thunderer. I could easily see your god called The Sailor, or The Trickster. The need to have short things to call the gods is inescapable but title work as well as names for this purpose. Even in common usage to this day we have these, The Grim Reaper and Mother Nature.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. As described, they make not much sense. Why is it like that? What created this pantheon, or how did it form? Why abstract things have whims?

If sentient beings channeling their rituals are somehow determining the deities domains and personality over the centuries, it would explain what is happening. Otherwise it's arbitrary, which per se is not bad, but needs more explaining.

Comment: One explanation would be divine paranoia about name magic. Or the gods actually go by their True Names which they aren't about to make public knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I would see with this idea is how the gods communicate with each other, as they are a pantheon of abstract beings I imagine at some point they will interact somehow, be it friendly or in war. Even if they don't give themselves a name surely other gods would find names for each other, otherwise how will they address each other?

The humans can create different factions of worship under their own versions of the god which they created more for their own gains, see Hinduism, it is essentially one god but sub divided into many, mostly because people wanted more power.

You could write a complicated story of how the worshippers name the god and fight for which is the correct name but I still think the main problem will be confusion between the gods themselves, unless you find a way around that.